# Magento : Fatal Error Mage_Core_Model_Config::getResourceHelper While Migrating From Magento 1.5.1 to 1.6.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have following error after my upgrade :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Config::getResourceHelper() in /home/koala/dev/magento/koala/app/Mage.php on line 531
```

I ve set up some debug here :

```
/**
 * Retreive resource helper object
 *
 * @param string $moduleName
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Helper_Abstract
 */
public static function getResourceHelper($moduleName)
{
    $registryKey = '_resource_helper/' . $moduleName;
    var_dump($registryKey);
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getResourceHelper($moduleName);
        self::register($registryKey, $helperClass);
    }

    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

And the resource helper called is :

```
string(21) "_resource_helper/core"
```

I had a deeper look in places where is called

> Mage::getResourceHelper('core')

and I notice that all came from app/code/core, so I don't think it came from some changes I made in local / community folders.

Does anyone had and fixed this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, we had in local an override on app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php that was broken